# setTimeout or setInterval or requestAnimationFrame

Tags: html, canvas, settimeout, setinterval, requestanimationframe

For HTML5 games,with canvas animation for mobile devices.

I'm facing some performance issues which differ the speed between each device and the others.

**requestAnimationFrame** speed the animation of the game according to the device speed.
**setInterval** shocked me that there are a delay from a device to another.
**setTimeout** is also slow the drawing on canvas.

Who had a previous experience with Mobile HTML5 games can guide me throw the best way of three of them (or other techniques if available) for developing animation on canvas be stable on different mobile devices ?

Answer (score 21):

Always use `requestAnimationFrame` when possible, since that's what it's meant for. It's best to [use a shim for support](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671) when it isn't, so you don't need to deal with the specific details.

In order for animation or game logic to perform at the same speed despite the actual method used, you should use time based animation and time based calculations for physics or such.

Comment: The old versions on android phone browsers doesn't support requestAnimationFrame (HTC) .... I try this site http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/RequestAnimationFrame/Default.html on the HTC device and it is NOT supported !!

Comment: @Solieman Paul Irish has a great blog post with a requestAnimationFrame shim: http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: @Solieman the code I linked (the shim) takes care of using the correct method. If `requestAnimationFrame` isn't supported, it will automatically use one of the other methods. Jasper's link has more info on it.

Comment: +1. This thread is also relevant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508085/requestanimationframe-running-slow-on-weak-machines-work-around

Answer (score 10):

```
window.requestAnimFrame = function(){
    return (
        window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
        function(/* function */ draw1){
            window.setTimeout(draw1, 1000 / 60);
        }
    );
}();
   window.requestAnimFrame(draw);
})();
```

use this function for all cases

Comment: what does the `1000 / 60` do?  why not just a simple `resultant / evaluated` figure ? and apart from this is  a copied solution from [`GitHub`](https://gist.github.com/mrdoob/838785) without giving credits to the original poster

Comment: 60 frames per second

Answer (score 0):

OPTIMIZATION
requestAnimationFrame() since its introduction was very CPU friendly, causing animations to stop if the current window or tab is not visible.

https://flaviocopes.com/requestanimationframe/

```
 var count = 0;
    const IDS = requestAnimationFrame(repeatOften);

        function repeatOften() {
            count++;
            if(count > 4 ){
                // cancelAnimationFrame (IDS);
                 console.warn('finish');
                 return;
            }
            console.log('init' + count);
            // Do whatever
            requestAnimationFrame(repeatOften);
        }
```