# I cannot resize the Canvas in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Ok, so, I'm working on a project in HTML5 and JavaScript. I'm trying to resize a Canvas, but it won't work. I don't think it's my browser, though, because I am using the latest version of FireFox. I've also researched this issue for a while, and I am confident I'm doing this correctly. So, I don't know why it won't work.
Here's my Code:

```
var level = 1;
var levelImg = undefined;
var width = 0;
var height = 0;

var cnvs = document.getElementById("cnvs").getContext("2d");

width = window.innerWidth
    || document.documentElement.clientWidth
    || document.body.clientWidth;

height = window.innerHeight
    || document.documentElement.cleintHeight
    || document.body.cleintHeight;

cnvs.width = width;
cnvs.height = height;

window.onload = function Init(){

    levelImg = document.getElementById("level" + level);

    setInterval("Draw()", 3);

}

function Draw(){

    //Clear the Screen
    cnvs.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    //Draw stuff
    DrawLevel();

}

function DrawLevel(){
    cnvs.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have some typos in your code.

Comment: [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: "How can I debug my JavaScript Code" = Use typescript.

Answer (score 0):

First correct all the typos in you code.
Use the browser console to detect errors.

#### Difference between canvas and the context

```
var cnvs = document.getElementById("cnvs").getContext("2d");
```

`cnvs` variable is not a canvas but the `context` for the canvas.
Canvas is the element and context is the object used to write in the canvas.
To access the canvas you need to do this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("cnvs");
var cnvs = canvas.getContext('2d'); //context
```

Now when you are trying to change the canvas with, you use canvas, not `cnvs`.

```
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
```

`SetInterval` expects a function and a number value that represents milliseconds.
`"Draw()"` is a string, not a function, and `3` is a really small number between each time the browser draws on canvas. It works, but it's very inefficient.

Other point about setInterval. Avoid it by using `requestAnimationFrame()` instead.
Take a look here: [setTimeout or setInterval or requestAnimationFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935262/settimeout-or-setinterval-or-requestanimationframe)

Defining `var levelImg = undefined` has no utility. It can be replaced by    `var levelImg;`

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. Didn't notice the 'cleint' typo tho... :)